# Reliable cattery at Paris Charles de Gaulle Airport (CDG)

Tags: air-travel, airports, cdg, pets

My wife and I will be travelling with two cats in September, changing flights at the Charles de Gaulle Airport. It's a long travel so it's important that the cats can take a break, stretch their legs and use the toilet during the layover. Is there a reliable cattery at the airport?

So far, we have been able to find two catteries - Air Transport Animals and Golden Way - but there is very little information online available about either, and after hearing various horror stories about pets in air transportation, we are a little wary (or perhaps a little paranoid).

Comment: Are the cats traveling in the cabin with you or in the hold?

Comment: The cats are travelling in the cabin.

Comment: Cats being cats are probably going to want to hunker down in their carriers and not likely going to want to stretch their legs or use a toilet during a layover.  My advice is to line the  carriers with absorbent pads and change them as needed.  I flew 2 cats like that last year.  Also check with your vet for calming drugs and how and when to administer them.

Comment: It's likely that these facilities are currently closed due to COVID, you should call ahead to confirm.